# Validate phone number in java set method?

Tags: java

I am learning Java for the first time, and a homework question asks that we create an address list, where invalid characters are caught in our phone number formats. Can I do this through a 'set' method? My code is as following:

```
    public void sethomePhone(String value) {
    String regex = "^\\(?([0-9]{3})\\)?[-.\\s]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]
                    {4})$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    if (matcher.matches() == true){
        homePhone = value;
    } else {
        System.out.println(value + "is not a valid phone number.");
    }
```

This doesn't seem to be working though, since when I test it in the main class even invalid phone numbers are getting passed through as valid. Do I need to create a separate method for this?

Thanks, and sorry if this is a stupid question; I'm only a month in!

---

Thanks all for answering. I modified the code trying both suggested regex formats, and it's still allowing invalid numbers through. I tried:

```
public void sethomePhone(String value) {
    String regex = "^(([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{4}))$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    if (matcher.matches()){
        homePhone = value;
    } else {
        System.out.println(value + "is not a valid phone number.");
    }
```

And then input the following test in my Main method (includes other fields):

```
  AddressBook person3 = new AddressBook("Dark", "Wing", "Duck", "Duckville",
  "123-245-6799", "123-49*51", "123-456-7891", 
  "@skypedarkdefender","letsgetdangerous", "www.darkwing.com");
```

which output:

- First Name: Dark
- Middle Name: Wing
- Last Name: Duck
- Home Phone: 123-49*51
- Business Phone: 123-245-6799
- Cellphone: 123-456-7891
- Home Address: Duckville
- Facebook ID: letsgetdangerous
- Skype ID: @skypedarkdefender
- Personal Website: www.darkwing.com

Sorry; I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong... but thanks for all the help to date!

Comment: Have you checked that the regex is valid?

Comment: note: if (matcher.matches() == true) can simply be written if (matcher.matches())

Comment: Could you try the second answer and let me know if it works for you? I've updated the regex to fix an issue with parens.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I've tried that too, and the same invalid code is still going through. i'll keep trying!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
String regex = "^(([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{3})[-.\\s]?([0-9]{4}))$";
```

[image: Regex results]

http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]{0,1}[-\\.\\s]?(\\d{3}|\\(\\d{3}\\))[-\\.\\s]?[0-9]{3}[-\\.\\s]?[0-9]{4})$");
```

Country code: No more than 1 digit (optional)

-,.,\s (optional)

Open paren,3 digits Closed paren OR 3 digits

-,.,\s (optional)

3 digits

-,.,\s (optional)

4 digits

Comment: It's not valid to match `(111` or `111)` but must match `(111)` and `111` for area codes. So the parens are only optional as a set.

Comment: I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write the regex but I've updated my answer.

Comment: @twain249 - thanks! I changed the regex to match either 3 digits or 3 digits inside parens.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to update to say I figured it out. I moved the regex out of my "set" method, and into the constructor:

```
private String firstName; // First name of the contact. 
private String middleName; // Middle name of the contact. 
private String lastName; //Last name of the contact.
private String homeAddress; //Contact home address.
private String businessPhone; //Contact business phone number.
private String homePhone; //Contact home phone number.
private String cellphone; //Contact cell phone number.
private String skypeId; // Contact Skype ID.
private String facebookId; //Contact Facebook ID.
private String personalWebSite; //Contact personal website URL.

/**
 * Create a new instance of class AddressBook. Initialize instance variables
 * to values of the arguments passed through the constructor parameters. All
 * parameters defined through the variable list are defined in this
 * instance.
 *
 * @param fn - First name of the contact.
 * @param mn - Middle name of the contact.
 * @param ln - Last name of the contact.
 * @param homeAddress - Contact home address.
 * @param businessPhone - Contact business phone number.
 * @param homePhone - Contact home phone number.
 * @param cellphone - Contact cell phone number.
 * @param skypeId - Contact Skype ID.
 * @param facebookId - Contact Facebook ID.
 * @param personalWebSite - Contact personal website URL.
 */
public AddressBook(String fn, String mn, String ln,
        String homeAddress, String businessPhone, String homePhone,
        String cellphone, String skypeId, String facebookId,
        String personalWebSite) {
    this.businessPhone = businessPhone;
    this.cellphone = cellphone;
    this.facebookId = facebookId;
    this.firstName = fn;
    this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    this.homePhone = homePhone;
    this.lastName = ln;
    this.middleName = mn;
    this.personalWebSite = personalWebSite;
    this.skypeId = skypeId;

    String regex = ("^([0-9]{0,1}[-\\.\\s]?(\\d{3}|\\(\\d{3}\\))[-\\.\\s]?[0-9]{3}[-\\.\\s]?[0-9]{4})$");
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(homePhone);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        homePhone = homePhone;
    } else {
        homePhone = ("invalid phone number.");
    }
    System.out.println("First Name: " + fn);
    System.out.println("Middle Name: " + mn);
    System.out.println("Last Name: " + ln);
    System.out.println("Home Phone: " + homePhone);
    System.out.println("Business Phone: " + businessPhone);
    System.out.println("Cellphone: " + cellphone);
    System.out.println("Home Address: " + homeAddress);
    System.out.println("Facebook ID: " + facebookId);
    System.out.println("Skype ID: " + skypeId);
    System.out.println("Personal Website: " + personalWebSite);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Thanks all for the help!